# Go Parse HTML table

Tags: html, go, web-scraping

I have a table in html that I would like to parse.  Something like the one in the following
http://sprunge.us/IJUC
However, I'm not sure of a good way to parse out the information.  I've seen a couple of html parsers, but those seem to require that everything has a special tag for you to parse it like info to grab; however, the majority of my info is within `<td></td>`

Does anyone have a suggestion for parsing this information out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Shameless plug: My [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) library. It's the jQuery syntax brought to Go (requires Go's [experimental html package](https://code.google.com/p/go.net/html), see instructions in the README of the library).

So you can do things like that (assuming your HTML document is loaded in doc, a `*goquery.Document`):

```
doc.Find("td").Each(func (i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
  fmt.Printf("Content of cell %d: %s\n", i, s.Text())
})
```

Edit: Change `doc.Root.Find` to `doc.Find` in the example since a goquery Document is now a Selection too (new in v0.2/master branch)

Comment: Nice package but Im having problems using it. Im importing it but the compiler is telling me that Document and NewDocument are undefined ?

Comment: Can you open an issue on GitHub with an excerpt from your code and the steps you've taken to install it? I'll give it a look.

Comment: Im new to Go so most probably Im doing something wrong. Im on a Mac and Ive used Homebrew to install Go (1.0.3). Running "go get github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery" seems to have installed the package in /usr/local//Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery.

Comment: Never mind I found the problem. I should read comments more closely :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in Go's experimental HTML parser:
https://code.google.com/p/go.net/html

The package definition according to the godoc:

> Package html implements an HTML5-compliant tokenizer and parser

I haven't used it myself, but it seems pretty straight-forward:

> Parsing is done by calling Parse with an io.Reader, which returns the
>   root of the parse tree (the document element) as a *Node. It is the
>   caller's responsibility to ensure that the Reader provides UTF-8
>   encoded HTML.

```
go get code.google.com/p/go.net/html

import "code.google.com/p/go.net/html"

doc, err := html.Parse(r)
```

It is not part of any current release, but can be used if you **install from source**, or use the golang-tip ubuntu apt repo.

**EDIT**: you can also use the following mirror of the experimental Go packages here: https://github.com/kless/go-exp

```
go get github.com/kless/go-exp/html

import (
    "github.com/kless/go-exp/html"
)
```

Comment: Is there any indication as to when this package is going to be promoted to the standard lib?

Comment: The experimental HTML parser has been moved to https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=net . As for when it'll be promoted, in August '12 the maintainer stated that it was very close to passing the Webkit test suite, but wouldn't be promoted until the API could be frozen, and he wasn't ready for that.

Answer (score -1):

If your HTML is well-formed, you can use the built-in XML parser:

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/

Comment: Everything I see regarding using the xml package assumes you have tag names like <name></name> or <foo></foo>.  How do I just read through all of my table rows?

Comment: @sorcix A well formed HTML isn't XML. Are you confusing HTML and XHTML ?